# MacRuby, sheet error

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macos, macruby

I'm running with MacRuby 0.5 and I have a method:

```
 attr_accessor :bookmarkSheet, :mainWindow

def createBookmark(sender)
  NSApp.beginSheet(bookmarkSheet, 
   modalForWindow:mainWindow, 
   modalDelegate:self, 
   didEndSelector:nil,
   contextInfo:nil)   
 end
```

which is supposed to open up a sheet panel on the main window. However, whenever I run this method, I get

```
2009-10-10 12:27:45.270 Application[45467:a0f] nil is not a symbol
```

Any thoughts as to why I get this error? I can't seem to find anywhere that lists the reason I am getting this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter is right, didEndSelector: is expecting a selector, you should try something like:

```
def bookmark_created
 puts "Bookmark created"
end

def createBookmark(sender)
  NSApp.beginSheet(bookmarkSheet, 
   modalForWindow:mainWindow, 
   modalDelegate:self, 
   didEndSelector:"bookmark_created:",
   contextInfo:nil)   
 end
```

Notice how I added a colon after the name of the method to call.
Also, it looks like a bug with MacRuby beta release, I would encourage you to report the bug on the MacRuby tracker: http://www.macruby.org/trac/newticket

Here is the example given by Apple's documentation:

```
- (void)showCustomDialog: (NSWindow *)window
// User has asked to see the dialog. Display it.
{
    if (!myCustomDialog)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"MyCustomDialog" owner: self];

    [NSApp beginSheet: myCustomDialog
            modalForWindow: window
            modalDelegate: nil
            didEndSelector: nil
            contextInfo: nil];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow: myCustomDialog];
    // Dialog is up here.
    [NSApp endSheet: myCustomDialog];
    [myCustomDialog orderOut: self];
}
```

As you can see, you should be able to set the end selector as nil. In the meantime, my workaround will work just fine.

Good luck,

- Matt

Comment: perfect. note though, mine did not require that extra colon after the method name. it worked that way, but threw an exception. thanks for the help guys. any clue as to why that error is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're passing `nil` as the `didEndSelector:`. You need to pass a selector there.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note for everybody reading this thread. When finding bugs in MacRuby, even if you are not sure, please email the mailing list http://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/macruby-devel and file a bug report: https://www.macruby.org/trac/newticket

You can certainly also post here and ask on Twitter but if you find something wrong with MacRuby and you want it fixed, you really really need to file a bug report.

**Update:** ticket filed [here](http://www.macruby.org/trac/ticket/379). (check on the ticket for status update)

Thanks,

Comment: You guys are fast. Bug is fixed!